# 3DSMAX 2011 Scripting - How to clone and rename bones

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm a total newbie with 3DSMAX scripting.

I need to clone bones by their name and rename the "cloned bone" with specific names.

For exemple:

I must clone `bip_01_Lhand` and rename the clone as `_bone_weapon_attachment` and move cloned bone `10 units of distance` on `X axis`

Same for `bip01_head` whose clone must become `_bone_hat_attachment`and move cloned bone `15 units of distance` on `Y axis`

How can I do that? (obs:I've tried to do that by myself, but failed when I couldn't create an array properly)

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, try gamedev.stackexchange.com ; there are some tools programmers there. (I wish I could help you myself but we're a Maya shop.)

Comment: Will do! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The gist of what you want to do is quite common in technical art/animation.

If the changes you need to apply are different for each bone, then you won't have much of a choice but create some kind of mapping. In python, this can be easily done with a dictionary. If you're using maxscript, an option is to create a multi dimensional array whereby each array item is an array starting with the item you're looking for, the second item is the name of the clone, and the third is the offset.

Then simply iterate through each bone of your rig, clone the intended bones, and apply the offset you stored in the mapping.

Here's an example:

```
mapping = #(
    #("bip_01_Lhand ", "_bone_weapon_attachment", [10, 0, 0]),
    #("bip01_head", "_bone_hat_attachmentand", [0, 15, 0])
)    

selectedNodes = getCurrentSelection()

for s in selectedNodes do
(
    -- for each item in the selection, go through each mapping and 
    -- see if a match can be found
    for m in mapping do
    (
        -- m is an array, so fetch each item of the array
        name = m[1]
        targetName = m[2]
        offset = m[3]
        -- verify that the names match, otherwise move on to the next
        if s.name == name then
        (
            cloneObj = copy s
            cloneObj.name = targetName
            cloneObj.position += offset
        )
    )

)
```